# How to set up the layout of the alignment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I don't know how to set up the layout of the alignment? Maybe this is a simple question but i am no idea,And I'm a new Android developer.Please provide the way of thinking,Thank you!
[This is my page to display hierarchical relationship.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOoE1.jpg)

This page is made up of two layout, parent and child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/table_cell_bg_color">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/parent_task_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="40px"
            android:paddingTop="6px"
            android:paddingBottom="6px"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#2B2B2B"
            android:text="No data"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ram_arrow_close"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/table_cell_bg_color" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_task_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:paddingLeft="60px"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#2B2B2B"
        android:text="No Data" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_task_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:paddingLeft="60px"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:paddingBottom="10px"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
        android:text="No Data"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/ram_arrow_icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is a result from json. I want the numbers to be in one column！How to fix it?

Comment: Try TableLayout and TableRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this Code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/table_cell_bg_color">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/child_task_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#2B2B2B"
    android:text="No Data" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/arrow_layout"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow_layout"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/arrow_layout"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_task_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/text_blue"
        android:text="No Data"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/arrow_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ram_arrow_icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I thing you are using list view or recyclerview so you should use this view to repeat the content based on array size

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions for you.

1. [Table Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html)
2. [Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use with layout

```
android:gravity=""
```

and

```
android:layout_gravity=""
```